# this.userId in meteor insert function does not get returned

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following code and when I try to grab the `this.userId` I can't seem to get the value entered into the db. It works on the front end throug pub sub not sure how to solve this and if I use Meteor.userId() I get a error saying it can't be used in publish functions.

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { Accounts } from "meteor/accounts-base";
import {
  LeadsCollection,
  LeadsBuilderCollection,
} from "/imports/api/LeadsCollection";
import "/imports/api/leadsMethods";
import "/imports/api/leadsPublications";

const insertLead = (leadEmail) =>
  LeadsCollection.insert({
    email: leadEmail,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    userId: this.userId,
  });
const insertLeadBuilderType = (leadsBuilder) =>
  LeadsBuilderCollection.insert({ type: leadsBuilder });

const SEED_USERNAME = "admin";
const SEED_PASSWORD = "admin";

Meteor.startup(() => {
  if (!Accounts.findUserByUsername(SEED_USERNAME)) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      username: SEED_USERNAME,
      password: SEED_PASSWORD,
    });
  }
  if (LeadsCollection.find().count() === 0) {
    [
      "First Lead",
      "Second Lead",
      "Third Lead",
      "Fourth Lead",
      "Fifth Lead",
      "Sixth Lead",
      "Seventh Lead",
    ].forEach(insertLead);
  }
  if (LeadsBuilderCollection.find().count() === 0) {
    ["Showroom Lead", "Phone Call Lead", "Website Lead"].forEach(
      insertLeadBuilderType
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: One sidenote. You should use Meteor.settings for seed Username and Default password. Even better is to omit the password and send an invitation email.

Comment: good thing to note, right now it's just being developed, but I'll add that in before testing with real people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.userId` is not set in any way because this code runs on startup, not in the context of a method call or publication to a client. So you'll need to be explicit about the userId:

```
const userId = Accounts.findUserByUsername(SEED_USERNAME)?._id ||
    Accounts.createUser({
      username: SEED_USERNAME,
      password: SEED_PASSWORD,
    });
```

You then need to give that `userId` to your `insertLead` function, e.g.:

```
   ...
    ].forEach(lead => insertLead(lead, userId));
```

and change the function to:

```
const insertLead = (leadEmail, userId) =>
  LeadsCollection.insert({
    email: leadEmail,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    userId,
  });
```

Comment: is it normal that the id for th user is different, and it's 1,2,3,4 for different documents, should they not be all the same user ID and much longer?

Comment: and what exactly is happening at this part here `?._id ||` I know that it's a or statment and a if statement but what's going on here in context.

Comment: is it saying if user._id exists return this value, or if not return createUservalue?

Comment: weird when I console the userId constant I get the right userId, but it's inserting 0,1,2...

Comment: oh i messed it up on the insertLead function all good working now :)